# Aligning Elements Properly in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to align elements in a coordinator layout. The code is as follows :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="HAHAHA" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Related"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

On implementing the code above I am getting : [image]

But I want the layout to be properly aligned, something like :

[image]

This happens when I enclose the first `linear layout` in an `AppBarLayout`. This is not the correct way to go about this. What is the correct way to align elements in a `coordinator layout`?

Answer (score 0):

updated my answer,check this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="HAHAHA" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Info"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Friends"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Related"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_book"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: this removes the first text view no? that is incorrect

You have removed the first linear layout with the button.

Comment: `<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="HAHAHA" />
                </RelativeLayout>`


This relative layout is not present in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the views within the app bar into an `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HAHAHA" />

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Using an `AppBarLayout` is the correct way of doing this. Refer to the source code for [CheeseSquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml#L61) (the app maintained by Google to showcase the correct use of Material Design Support Library) to know more about AppBarLayout and it's uses.

Comment: Exactly, what if I want to use a `linear layout` without using the app bar layout? That is precisely my question. If I do not use `app bar layout`, is there a way to achieve scroll?